# Use of Exported Symbols File option in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing a stating library for iOS device. I would like to export only few global symbols. I created a .txt file and added the symbols to be exported . I added this file in the project under Resources group. I added the name of the file in "Exported Symbols File" linker flag. I generate the .a library file and run nm -g command on it. I was hoping to see only the symbols that were added in the export symbol file, but the command shows all global symbols. Am I using the nm command correctly. Is there another way to find symbols in the global table?

Comment: Are you stripping symbols? If not, a debug version of your app will have them anyway so that the debugger can find them when a crash happens or you set a breakpoint.

Comment: I did use the other Xcode flags to strip debug symbols, but it still shows